# jQuery remove text from image src attribute

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I want to change the src attribute on hover. For example, I have the following HTML:

```
<img src="convert.php?image=images/example.jpg" alt="#" />
```

On hover, I want to remove the "convert.php?" string so that the HTML is:

```
<img src="image=images/example.jpg" alt="#" />
```

Must be simple?

Answer (score 2):

Answered own question. Found this snippet.

```
$('.item img').each(function(e){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).hover(function(){
      $(this).attr('src', src.replace('convert.php?image=', ''));
    }, function(){
     $(this).attr('src', src);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Except that doesn't replace like the example given in the question, but I expect it's what you actually meant.

Answer (score 0):

Can use `attr(function(){}`

Following will restore image on `mouseleave` as well

```
$(".item img").hover(function () {
      var convert='convert.php?image=';
     $(this).attr('src',function(idx, attr){
          return attr.indexOf(convert) <0 ? convert+attr : attr.replace(convert,'');
     });
});
```

When only one function passed as argument to hover it will run for both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events

Answer (score -1):

```
  $("img").hover(
      function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        jQuery.data(this, 'old_source', src);
        srcNew = src.replace("convert.php?", "");
        $(this).attr('src', srcNew);
        $(this)., srcNew);
      },
      function () {
        var src = $(this).data('old_source');
        $(this).attr('src', src);
      }
    );
```

Comment: won't work as `src` is undefined in second handler, it only has scope in first handler